# How to pass bash commands from a script to terminal?

Tags: shell, ess, ansi-term, bash

Let's say I have a bash script. Is there a way I can pass specific lines or blocks in the script to terminal process in EMACS? Just like how we do for R script using command `C-c R`

Comment: I found that I can highlight the region and use command `sh-execute-region` (bound to `C-M-x`). However, every time it is running the command in a new shell process. Is there a way to keep running all subsequent commands in the same shell process?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286579/emacs-shell-mode-how-to-send-region-to-shell